# Running eclipse SRC

Tags: eclipse, src

I'm having a very basic problem getting started with eclipse. [image].

I just set up eclipse and am trying to run the "helloworld" script and getting errors with the SRC it looks like. Any advice?

Comment: Move what you have at line 10 to line 6.

Comment: Eclipse is telling you that your code is not valid. Statements must be within a method so your code at line 10 needs to be moved to be within `main` (line 6). Also it is `println` not `printin` (`l` not `i`).